# Rename files into sub directories

Tags: linux, rename

I'm attempting to rename a bunch of files with 'rename' and I have my regex nicely setup:

`rename --verbose --path 's|^\[(....)\](.*)\.(.*)|$2 ($1).$3|' *`

But I'd really like to have each file put into a directory with the common start, so nievely I tried:

`rename --verbose --path 's|^\[(....)\](.*)\.(.*)|$2 ($1)/$2 ($1).$3|' *`

But that complains that none of the directories exist (as they don't). Am I missing a useful flag for rename or is their a better tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Perl-based `rename`, then there is nothing stopping you from calling `mkdir()` to create the missing directories:

```
rename --verbose '
    s|^\[(....)\](.*)\.(.*)|$2 ($1)/$2 ($1).$3| &&
    mkdir("$2 ($1)")' *
```

This is the same Perl expression that you use, with an added call to `mkdir()` at the end to create the directory if the expression matches.

Whether the original substitution is correct or not, or whether it makes sense, I don't know (I don't know what types of filenames you have).  The point is that since the expression is a generic Perl expression, you're free to use any Perl code, as long as `$_` (the default variable) is set to the resulting filename at the end.

Comment: Thank you. That is both weird and awesome that works. 

Many uses for this knowledge.